# Accepted for Masters but Can Only Attend if I Have a Scholarship

Tags: masters, funding

I'm not a US citizen, and I was accepted recently for an MS Degree in CS. After asking the Graduate Office, I was told so far they don't have a scholarship for me (only 15 out of the 115 accepted got one).

I'm proceeding with the papers and such, since if someone drops, it will pass the scholarship for the next one, but due to currency exchange and the high price of US education, I can't go without the funding. Is there any way I can prove myself now or is it better to refuse the offer right now?

Comment: Any chance of an on-campus job if you don't get a scholarship?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Unless I can pay the whole tuition, unfortunately no :(

Answer (score 2):

Ask if you are eligible for student loan.

Scholarships are often not available for undergraduate and Master's degree. It is extremely common in the US (and UK) that students borrow money to pay tuition fee and stipend. My former flatmate didn't paid all the loan until he was 28 years old (his father paid his tuition fee, he only borrowed for stipend). You can consider this as an investment if you believe the degree could bring you a well-paid job in the future.

On the other hand, you don't have to go the US to do a Master's. Many EU countries, such as Germany, provide free education for foreigners, and many provide scholarships based on the household income.

Answer (score -3):

It seems to be a Hypothetical question. However, my advice is to but for some financial aids to study if you really believe it's worth doing.